# Use a "pass through" api to gate access to another application

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, webapi

We have an application that runs on VMs in Azure Service Fabric. They are accessed by way of a Azure API Management. Currently we are gating access in API Management, but would like to get more flexible by integrating with AAD. We are unable to add AAD auth to the actual application. I have looked at doing something with Policies in APIM, but they are a bit cumbersome and hard to test for our scenario.

What I would like to do is to create a simple WebApi that would authenticate (handling both OAuth client API calls as well as browser sessions with interactive login) the call and, if authenticated (and in the correct group), forward that request to the localhost port where the target app resides.

What would be the easiest way to go about this? In this process I need to be able to handle the app returning a webpage for interaction and not simply a response with payload. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what is exact flow you are looking for and what type of application you are using?

Comment: Hi @John are you still looking for any help on this?